# How to analyze app battery performance

Tags: android

My app is draining the battery also when its not in foreground and i can't figure out why.

I have one background service for a chat room (using [realtime](http://framework.realtime.co/messaging/)).

Is there any tool for analysing app battery performance?

Not an app like battery doctor.
I want to check exactly what Activity or Service is draining the battery.

Thanks

Comment: Have you watched Google's Android Performance Patterns videos: https://youtu.be/fEEulSk1kNY?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE

Comment: Little Eye Labs had a great solution but they're not available anymore. Anyone knows a good alternative to test battery performance with automatic builds?